# renaming @UniqueConstraint doesn't work

Tags: jpa, unique

I have an entity where I put a composed UniqueConstraint, and try to rename this constraint by using the "name" attribute :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ApplicatifTerminal", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "UniqueApplicatifTerminal", columnNames = {
        "idApplicatif", "idTerminal" }))
public class ApplicatifTerminalDo {
```

........

But the name of the constraint is not changed, even when regenerating the DB, and stay with the default name of "idAttribute".
It's not a blocking problem, I'm aware. But I would like to know why this attribute name doesn't work.

PS : I use hibernate 4.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it should be renamed: Hibernate does not know that it is the same constraint that it generated earlier in another deployment. You will have to do that manually.

But Hibernate should create an unique constraint with that name, if none is existent ON TABLE GENERATION.
Indeed it seems to be a bug in Hibernate 4.0.1 (which creates the constraint with the name of the first column only on new table schema generation) which is solved in 4.3.0 (which creates the constraint with the correct name, even if the table already exists).

Comment: Yes but, even when regenerating / redeploying the database it doesn't put the name passed in annotation's attribute "name"

Comment: As I see in my tests: in order to generate the key, the table must not exist. Also you are right: the name of the constraint is not considered: you should report this as bug to the Hibernate team.

Comment: @user3332598 I changed my answer: it is a bug in 4.0.1 but at least in 4.3.0 it works perfectly.